# Convert sql query to KQL

Tags: sql, kql

I have one sql query.
I want to convert this query to kql same with offset and fetch

```
SELECT Empname
  FROM Emp
 OFFSET 500 ROWS
 FETCH NEXT 1000 ROWS ONLY
```

I want to use to query to ADF pipeline.

Comment: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can do the trick:

```
Emp
| order by SomeColumn asc
| extend RowNumber = row_number()
| where RowNumber between (500 .. 1499)
| project EmpName
```

But it's not the right way to work with Kusto. Here's why:

- Why would you want to get only these 1000 records, from this specific offset? This doesn't make sense as the data in Kusto is not sorted, so you have to sort by something. And in any case I assume that data is constantly being added to the table.
- Why don't you have any filters except the row number? What do you want to achieve with this query?

[Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ocmfWMPqZPM)'s a good video that will help you get started with KQL.

Comment: Basically I am working on Az data factory. and that we can process >5000 recodes at time for for this i have used two variable offset and fetch and i want to do Pagination based on parameters (OFFSET FETCH NEXT).